# Apache Flink Kakfa XML stream

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming, jackson-dataformat-xml

I get the following error when trying to run my Flink Streaming app.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply$mcV$sp(JobManager.scala:822)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.JobManager$$anonfun$handleMessage$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$7.apply(JobManager.scala:768)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:401)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.test.SwissProt: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
at [Source: [B@681c6d54; line: 1, column: 12]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1203)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2920)
at com.test.SwissProtDeserializationSchema.deserialize(SwissProtDeserializationSchema.scala:17)
at com.test.SwissProtDeserializationSchema.deserialize(SwissProtDeserializationSchema.scala:9)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KeyedDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:39)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.Kafka09Fetcher.run(Kafka09Fetcher.java:227)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I thought in Scala that when you made a case class, that the default constructor is created?  I do not understand the error.  Please help!

I have the following scala objects:

**Main scala object to run Flink Streaming**

```
package com.test

import java.util.Properties

import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer09

object Run {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
     val properties = new Properties()
     properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
     properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
     val rawStream = env.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09("XML", new SwissProtDeserializationSchema,properties))

     rawStream.print
     env.execute()
   }

 }
```

**Case Class that describes the input**

```
 package com.test

 case class SwissProt (name: String,
                       address: String,
                       phoneNumber: String,
                       cellPhoneNumber: String
                       ) {

 }
```

**Finally the deserialization class to extract the Kafka event into my case class object**

```
 package com.test

 import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.AbstractDeserializationSchema
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper

 class SwissProtDeserializationSchema extends AbstractDeserializationSchema[SwissProt]{
   private var xmlMapper: XmlMapper = null

   override def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): SwissProt = {
     if (xmlMapper == null) {
       xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
     }

     xmlMapper.readValue(bytes, classOf[SwissProt])
   }
 }
```

Comment: The compiler synthesizes a "factory" method in the companion object but I don't think it also synthesizes a default constructor (in the Java sense, a constructor with no parameters). It looks like the library you're using requires adherence to the Bean convention, therefore if you want to write it in Scala I'd suggest you create a normal class with `var`s, annotate them with @BeanProperty (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/11-annotations.html#java-beans-annotations) and add a default constructor (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874329/scala-constructor-without-parameters).

Comment: This for the info.  You made me take a closer look at the annotations for the jackson-dataformat-xml.  Turns out, I need to use @JacksonXmlProperty for a couple of my fields.  Also, I needed an additional case class to next into my original case class.  I will post the final class when I completely happy with it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to register the DefaultScalaModule.
So

```
    xmlMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

The scala import :
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule

The maven dependency:
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.5</version>
            </dependency>
```