# POJO's in Scala

Tags: scala, pojo

I have the following 2 classes in Java

```
public class DataPoint<T> {

    public long timeStampMs;
    public T value;

    public DataPoint() {}

    public DataPoint(long timeStampMs, T value) {
        this.timeStampMs = timeStampMs;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public <R> DataPoint<R> withNewValue(R newValue){
        return new DataPoint(this.timeStampMs, newValue);
    }
    public KeyedDataPoint withKey(String key){
        return new KeyedDataPoint(key, this.timeStampMs, this.value);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class KeyedDataPoint<T> extends DataPoint<T>{

    public String key;

    public KeyedDataPoint() {}

    public KeyedDataPoint(String key, long timeStampMs, T value) {
        super(timeStampMs, value);
        this.key = key;
    }

    public <R> KeyedDataPoint<R> withNewValue(R newValue){
        return new KeyedDataPoint(this.key, this.timeStampMs, newValue);
    }

}
```

I need to translate then into Scala:

```
class DataPoint[T] (@BeanProperty val timeStampMs: Long, @BeanProperty val value: T) {
    def withNewValue[R](value: R): DataPoint[R] = new DataPoint[R](timeStampMs, value)
    def withKey(key: String): KeyedDataPoint[T] = new KeyedDataPoint(key, timeStampMs, value)
}

class KeyedDataPoint[T](@BeanProperty val key: String,
                        @BeanProperty override val timeStampMs: Long,
                        @BeanProperty override val value: T) extends DataPoint (timeStampMs, value) {
}
```

The classes need to qualify as POJO's, but I can't figure out how to get it. If I provide a no-args primary constructor, then I don't know how to provide the multiple args auxiliary constructor, and viceversa ...if I leave the primary constructor for several arguments, then I don't know how to provide the no-args constructor demanded for POJO compliance. Any help?

Comment: Why would you want POJO in Scala? That's quite not the idiomatic was to represent data.

Comment: some frameworks (Spark, Flink) despite of the language binding, demand some classes to be POJO's for serialization purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class KeyedDataPoint[T](@BeanProperty val key: String,
                        @BeanProperty override val timeStampMs: Long,
                        @BeanProperty override val value: Option[T]) extends DataPoint (timeStampMs, value) {
}  

class DataPoint[T] (@BeanProperty val timeStampMs: Long, @BeanProperty val value: Option[T]) {
    def this() {
      this(0, None);
    }  
    def withNewValue[R](value: Option[R]): DataPoint[R] = new DataPoint(timeStampMs, value)
    def withKey(key: String): KeyedDataPoint[T] = new KeyedDataPoint(key, timeStampMs, value)
}
```

Comment: I tried avgolubev answer but I'm getting "Type mismatch, expected: T, actual: null". How do I pass a default value for a generic type such as T?

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the generic. See modified code.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working either, it throws the same error: "Type mismatch, expected: T, actual: None.type".

Comment: Strange, but I have this code compiles. In which line the error occurs?

Comment: I see the problem. I haven't realized that you have changed the parametric type to be an option in the primary constructor.
It feels a bit weird to me having an Option has a type... maybe it is because of my bias with Java-esque way of doing things.

Changing the type forces me to change the client code in a gazillion places. Is there an alternative to the use of Option, and passing some other default value? maybe something around the Nothing type?

Comment: I don't see any other way. Of course you can use the approach is described [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32797731/passing-a-type-parameter-for-instantiation), but it will not work in all cases. With Option you can use implicit conversion from T to Option[T] and the existing code will not have to be rewritten

Answer (score 3):

```scala
class Foo(s: String) {
    // alternative no-arg constructor (with different signature from primary)
    def this() {
        this("Default value from auxiliary constructor")
    }
}
```

please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874329/scala-constructor-without-parameters)